# Could you tell me how to rebuild bitcoin-core testnet node?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

It seems that my local bitcoin testnet node are corrupted. Could you tell me how to rebuild blocks?

The reason why I think it is corrupted is as following.

For example, when I checked transaction "ed2ccc36c241ad00893d0596fe167a4df162989dbf8c5ff3916d4034e7f510c3" on my local testnet node, it returned the following error.

```
error code: -5
error message:
No information available about transaction
```

However, on testnet block reader it returned transaction info.

[image]

Comment: Is this question different from your previous question? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41573/how-to-reinstall-bitcoin-core-testnet-blocks-from-scratch

Comment: Not different. However, I think this question is more simple. Therefore, I expect to delete the past one.

Comment: Dear Nick. 
Thank you for deleting my past question on behalf of me.

Comment: You're using get transaction on a non-wallet transaction, or getrawtransaction without enabling txindex.

Comment: Dear Pieter 
Does it mean I should add txindex=1 to bitcoin.conf file?